# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound Error - Already tried everything, still not working :/

Tags: java, apache, rest, maven, spring-mvc

I'm new to maven/spring and I'm struggling to figure out why I'm getting these errors. There are a bunch of questions like these online, however after attempting to use the solutions available, I was still unable to solve my error:

```
May 17, 2016 7:01:47 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/example/helloWorld/meow] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

My setup is as follows: Apache Tomcat (
I am trying to make a REST API that allows for me to upload and download files, as well as send messages back and forth via REST calls. I currently have 3 REST endpoints defined:

1. /helloWorld/hello -> GET
2. /helloWorld/displayMessage/{msg} -> GET
3. /helloWorld/meow -> POST

Right now, only calls 1 and 2 work, while three is what is causing the error above.

I am using terminal to ping each end point. Here is an example of a call I make to test 1 and 2:

```
curl -X GET localhost:8080/example/helloWorld/hello
```

This works.

However, I get a 404 response, as well as the error above, when I do this command:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/example/helloWorld/meow -d "{'body':1234}"
```

I'm pretty sure that the data I am sending is correct, but that hasn't reached a focus yet, because when I check my catalina.out file for my server, I see the error I mentioned above, meaning that I can't even debug my request because the URI doesnt work.

There is a front end defined, however I don't care for it, as I just need the REST calls.

Here's my Controller:

```
...imports...
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "JCG Hello World!");
        System.out.println(new Date().toString() + "testPrint: in hello");
        return "helloWorld";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/displayMessage/{msg}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayMessage(@PathVariable String msg, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        System.out.println(new Date().toString() + "testPrint: "+msg);
        return "helloWorld";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/meow", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    // @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveData(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
        String jsonString = request.getParameter("json");
        System.out.println(new Date().toString() + "testPrint: " + jsonString);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>serverExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springexample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>example</finalName>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"

    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value> /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml </param-value>
    </context-param>

   <listener>
    <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Here's my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.example.thing.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
<!--    
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
 -->
</beans>
```

Also, I have the line:

There is a * at the end of the package because I read one solution that said that adding the * fixed the problem, but it hasn't fixed mine, so I haven't taken it out yet. But it doesnt work with or without it.

Comment: can you test your method using Postman and see if you get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may miss `-H 'Content-Type:application/json'` in the command, try it;)

Comment: didn't work :( i'll keep trying different things, but putting that in the header now